# close panel on submit success

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, primeng

I am using `Primeng` and [overlay-panel](https://primefaces.org/primeng/#/overlaypanel), i am trying to close the panel on submitting success the form that shows in the panel.

the panel is loading the form, the form is a independent component:

### Main Page (uses the panel)

```
<p-overlayPanel #opCP dynamic="true" [showCloseIcon]="true">
  <app-command-packet-details [id]="taskId"></app-command-packet-details>
</p-overlayPanel>
```

### app-command-packet-details.html

loading the form...

### app-command-packet-details.ts

i want to close the panel from here

```
import { OverlayPanel } from 'primeng/overlaypanel';
...
export class CommandPacketDetailsComponent implements OnInit {

 ...
 @ViewChild("opCP") op: OverlayPanel; 
 ...

 this.renderSvc.resubmitCommandPacket(cPacket).subscribe(trans => {
      console.log(trans);
    },
      (err) => {
        console.error(err);
        this.messageSvc.add({ severity: 'error', summary: 'Error!', detail: 'Via command-packet.component' })
      },      
      () => {
        console.log("observable complete Success");
        // close the panel //////////////
        this.op.hide();
        ////////////////////////////////
        this.messageSvc.add({ severity: 'success', summary: 'Submit Success!', detail: 'Via command-packet.component' })
      }
    );
}
```

Chrome console shows this error

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'hide' of undefined

Comment: Where are you making this call? I think it will have to be in `ngAfterViewInit`

Comment: @ExplosionPills in a regular function..

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you exactly why because you haven't included the context of how this operation is called, but you are likely calling it before the view is rendered so the element doesn't exist yet. You'll want to educate yourself on how the lifecycle of angular components if this is a problem you aren't understanding.

See https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#lifecycle-sequence

You want to reference it after the view renders and the html exists since viewChild reads from the DOM. You'll want to kick this off after ngAfterViewInit fires. If you are running this in a loop, you could just test if this.op exists before you run it.

Really, though, viewChild is a last resort and I believe you could accomplish this better through template binding and a component attribute. Something like

### Main Page (uses the panel)

```
<p-overlayPanel dynamic="true" [showCloseIcon]="true" *ngIf="showOP">
  <app-command-packet-details [id]="taskId"></app-command-packet-details>
</p-overlayPanel>
```

### app-command-packet-details.ts

i want to close the panel from here

```
import { OverlayPanel } from 'primeng/overlaypanel';
...
export class CommandPacketDetailsComponent implements OnInit {

 ...
 // get rid of viewChild
 showOp = true;
 ...

 this.renderSvc.resubmitCommandPacket(cPacket).subscribe(trans => {
      console.log(trans);
    },
      (err) => {
        console.error(err);
        this.messageSvc.add({ severity: 'error', summary: 'Error!', detail: 'Via command-packet.component' })
      },      
      () => {
        console.log("observable complete Success");
        // close the panel //////////////
        this.showOp = false;
        ////////////////////////////////
        this.messageSvc.add({ severity: 'success', summary: 'Submit Success!', detail: 'Via command-packet.component' })
      }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got a way of doing this. Since the OverlayPanel is closed when a user clicks anywhere on the page, I got a way of dynamically clicking any DOM element to close this panel.

```
 dismissOverlay(event){
event.preventDefault();
let element : HTMLElement = document.getElementById("a valid DOM ID") as 
HTMLDivElement;
element.click()  }
```

You must pass the $event parameter from your html. For example,

```
<li (click)="exportExcel($event)">
```